# Term filter causes memory to spike drastically

Tags: elasticsearch, memory-leaks

The term filter that is used:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/my-index/my-doc-type/_search' -d '{
  "filter": {
    "term": {
      "void": false
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    [
      "user_id1",
      "user_name",
      "date",
      "status",
      "q1",
      "q1_unique_code",
      "q2",
      "q3"
    ]
  ],
  "size": 50000,
  "sort": [
    "date_value"
  ]
}'
```

- The `void` field is a `boolean` field.
- The index store size is 504mb.
- The elasticsearch setup consists of only a single node and the index
  consists of only a single shard and 0 replicas. The version of
  elasticsearch is 0.90.7
- The fields mentioned above is only the first 8 fields. The actual
  term filter that we execute has 350 fields mentioned.

**We noticed the memory spiking by about 2-3gb though the store size is only 504mb.**

**Running the query multiple times seems to continuously increase the memory.**

Could someone explain why this memory spike occurs?

Answer (score 0):

1. It's quite an old version of Elasticsearch
2. You're returning 50,000 records in one get
3. Sorting the 50k records
4. Your documents are pretty big - 350 fields.

Could you instead return a smaller number of records? and then page through them?
[Scan and Scroll](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scan-scroll.html) could help you.

it's not clear whether you've indexed individual fields - this could help as the _source being read from disk may be incurring a memory overhead.

Comment: The actual records matching the filter are only 17,000. This is for an export functionality so paging would not help.

Comment: What about the relation between store size and the spike we are experiencing?

Comment: 17k records returned is a big number. For the relationship between store size and spike, see the 2nd para in my answer.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the 2nd part?

Comment: What we've also noticed is that firing the above query multiple times seems to continuously increase the memory.